# Google Drive collaborative editor

Tags: google-drive-api

With the launch of Google Drive, i have been looking over the API and information available. I failed to find example or information that its even possible.

I would like to create a editor that two users can collaborate within at the same time. We all seen how google's own editor can do this.

The idea is for creating a demo where two programmers can work on the same project and work on the same files replacing subversion or other team solutions with a alternative solution.

Anyone able to find any examples in the google api or elsewhere, or better yet able to share some experience/code.

I assume its possible as WeVideo release an app for collaborate video editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Drive SDK doesn't offer this feature, sorry. Those apps that are achieving this are performing the collaborative aspects by themselves.

The SDK does support [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) so that your app can check that the file content has not been changed since it loaded the data, which will help.

Comment: Okay. A side question, if modifications are made to a file locally. Can one then upload the change only or does one need to upload the full file to commit changes?

Comment: Found out that it do not support differential upload.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive now has the [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/) (as of 2013, I think).